# find cube roots of $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz+1$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $x$,$y$, $z$ be real numbers such that $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 3xyz + 1$.

What is the smallest possible value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$?

Comment: Two questions: 1) To help people try to help you, it might be useful to know what you have tried. 2) What is the relation between your title and your question?

Answer (score 2):

**Lagrange Approach**

At any critical point of
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2\tag1
$$
under the condition
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz+1\tag2
$$
[Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) says we need a constant $\lambda$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
x(x-\lambda)=yz\tag3\\
y(y-\lambda)=zx\tag4\\
z(z-\lambda)=xy\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Multiplying $(3)$ by $x$, $(4)$ by $y$, and $(5)$ by $z$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
x^3-\lambda x^2=xyz\tag{6}\\
y^3-\lambda y^2=xyz\tag{7}\\
z^3-\lambda z^2=xyz\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Summing $(6)$, $(7)$, and $(8)$ says
$$
1=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=\lambda\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)\tag9
$$
Note that $(9)$ says that $\lambda\gt0$.

**Case $\bf{1}$: One of $\boldsymbol{x,y,z}$ is $\bf{0}$**

Suppose one of $x,y,z$ is $0$. Without loss of generality, say $x=0$. $(3)$ then implies that one or both of $y,z$ must also be $0$. Without loss of generality, say $y=0$. $(2)$ then implies that $z=1$. Thus, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

**Case $\bf{2}$: None of $\boldsymbol{x,y,z}$ is $\bf{0}$**

Suppose none of $x,y,z$ is $0$. $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ imply that
$$
\begin{align}
(x-\lambda)(y-\lambda)=z^2\tag{10}\\
(y-\lambda)(z-\lambda)=x^2\tag{11}\\
(z-\lambda)(x-\lambda)=y^2\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(11)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
yz
&=x^2-\lambda x\\
&=(y-\lambda)(z-\lambda)-\lambda x\\
0
&=\lambda^2-\lambda(x+y+z)\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lambda=x+y+z\tag{14}
$$
Adding $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ and applying $(14)$ yields
$$
xy+yz+zx=0\tag{15}
$$
which means, via $(9)$, $(14)$, and $(15)$,
$$
\overbrace{x^2+y^2+z^2}^{1/\lambda}=\overbrace{(x+y+z)^2}^{\lambda^2}\tag{16}
$$
Thus, $\lambda=1$, and $x^2+y^2+z^2\ge1$.

---

**$\boldsymbol{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ Can be Arbitrarily Large**

Note that we can make $x^2+y^2+z^2$ as large as we wish: let $y=-x$ and $x$ be arbitrarily large. Then $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz-1=z^3+3x^2z-1=0$ will always be satisfied by some real $z$. Then $x^2+y^2+z^2\ge2x^2$.

---

**Factorization Approach**

The Lagrange approach says that the minimum is $1$, so there is a good chance that the difference
$$
\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^3-\left(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz\right)^2
$$
might vanish at the critical points. The Lagrange approach also says that, at the critical points, $xy+yz+zx=0$, so it might be a factor. In fact, its square is a factor. The remaining factor is
$$
3x^2+3y^2+3z^2-2xy-2yz-2zx=(x+y-z)^2+(y+z-x)^2+(z+x-y)^2
$$
That is,
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^3-\overbrace{\left(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz\right)^2}^{\large1}\\
&=(xy+yz+zy)^2\left[(x+y-z)^2+(y+z-x)^2+(z+x-y)^2\right]\\
&\ge0
\end{align}
$$
Since $(0,0,1)$ satisfies $(2)$, the minimum of $(1)$ is $1$.

Comment: The Lagrange multipliers method is just a grind with a lot of algebra, but how did you see the factorisation approach?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @YiFan: I've moved the explanation into the answer, where it should be.